# Github GraphQL API V4: INSUFFICIENT_SCOPES

Tags: api, github, graphql, authorization, scoping

When I query GitHub's GraphQL API with the following:

```
query RetrievePackagesAssociatedWithRepo($repo: String!, $owner: String!) {
  repository(name: $repo, owner: $owner) {
    packages(packageType: NPM, first: 10) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          packageType
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I received an error stating:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "type": "INSUFFICIENT_SCOPES",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 11
        }
      ],
      "message": "Your token has not been granted the required scopes to execute this query. The 'id' field requires one of the following scopes: ['read:packages'], but your token has only been granted the: ['read:gpg_key', 'read:org', 'read:public_key', 'read:repo_hook', 'repo', 'user'] scopes. Please modify your token's scopes at: https://github.com/settings/tokens."
    },
```

I followed the link `https://github.com/settings/tokens` and added the necessary permissions.
I tried to Authorizing a personal access token for use with SAML single sign-on but, the SSO button to enable is not present.
[development settings token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Tih.png)

**Documentations I Followed:** *[Creating Personal Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)!* | *[Authorizing Personal Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/authorizing-a-personal-access-token-for-use-with-saml-single-sign-on)!*

After trying out theses methods, the same error message persists "*Your token has not been granted the required scopes*".

My goal, through Github's API, is to retrieve packages associated with its repository.

Is there something I'm missing.